# data comparison and finding optimal solution using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, logic

I have 2 tables. One has data for all the guests invited. Other has all the guests who came for the party. How would I check guests that did not come using SQL. Can you make it efficient assuming hypothetically there are 500k guests invited and 300k guests arrived.

If we have to use Script say bash script to automate it. What would the script look like?

Comment: we need to see the structure of the tables. With the information you have given us, the only answer is "write a query"

Comment: 1 column in each table. Attributes being Name. 500 rows in 1st and 300 rows in 2nd.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide complete structure of your db tables in question (CREATE TABLE statements and/or an ERD diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Im not really sure that name will be a unique enough key but, here is a query that will get rows from one table that do not exist on another:

```
SELECT name
FROM tablea
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT name FROM tableb)
;
```

Comment: The query in this answer will return *all* rows from tableA if tableB is empty (if there are zero rows in tableB.)  The query will return an empty set (zero rows) if tableB is not empty, if it contains at least one row. This query is valid, but I suspect it does not return the set that OP is looking to return. OP specified "data comparison" and seems to be returning guests that were invited but did not attend.

Comment: @spencer7593 I was under the impression that he only wanted to select guest that did not attend. If that is not the case, then my answer is indeed invalid.

Comment: If `tablea` represents guests that are invited, and `tableb` represents guests that attended... this query will return *all* of the guests that were invited, only when *no* guests attended. If even just one guest attended, then this query will return zero rows.  (The NOT EXISTS is only checking if the `SELECT name FROM tableb` subquery returns a row or not.)

Comment: @spencer7593 oh dear, I supposed I should delete this than.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the set operators are the simplest:

```
select name from invited
minus
select name from attended
```

Comment: Simple, but it does require a SORT.

Comment: I suppose it might use a sort, but i'm pretty sure that Oracle would choose a hash join in a lot of situations (depending on the table stats).  If so, that would only require a single pass through all the names in each table.  In the most ideal case, if both tables are indexed by name, then the name data is already presorted and available, and it would only be necessary to merge the index keys.

Comment: I have added an answer showing the difference between MINUS and ANTI-JOIN

Comment: I am really surprised at that result.  Forgive me for asking, but did you run dbms_stats.gather_table_stats before you generated the execution plans?

Comment: I think I probably did; it would have been amiss of me had I not. I can rerun it and double check.  Incidentally, I'm not surprised by the result :)

Answer (score 0):

With a suitable index defined, I'd use an anti-join pattern

```
 SELECT i.guest
   FROM invited i
     -- anti-join exclude
   LEFT
   JOIN attended a
     ON a.guest = i.guest 
  WHERE a.guest IS NULL
```

An equivalent result can be returned with other query patterns.

For example, a `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

```
 SELECT i.guest
   FROM invited i
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM attended a
                      WHERE a.guest = i.guest
                   )
```

The `EXPLAIN` output will likely show identical query access plans.

For optimum performance of those queries, we'd want an index defined

```
ON attended (guest)
```

Comment: Actually I think that the LEFT JOIN solution, testing for the null I think might be your best bet, using a table scan / hash join, rather than a nested loop / index lookup.I would certainly try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on an earlier comment, I want to demonstrate the difference between a MINUS and the ANTI JOIN

I have a table of INVITED about 1.8M and GUESTS (attended) about 1.1M

Using the MINUS,

```
select name from invited
minus
select name from attended

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |         |       |       |       | 14364 (100)|          |
|   1 |  MINUS              |         |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE       |         |  1835K|    10M|    21M|  8977   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| INVITED |  1835K|    10M|       |  3038   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   SORT UNIQUE       |         |  1101K|  6451K|    12M|  5388   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| GUESTS  |  1101K|  6451K|       |  1824   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the ANTI JOIN

```
SELECT i.name
   FROM invited i
     -- anti-join exclude
   LEFT
   JOIN guests g
     ON g.name = i.name
  WHERE g.name IS NULL
;


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |         |       |       |       |  7744 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI|         |  1835K|    21M|    18M|  7744   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | GUESTS  |  1101K|  6451K|       |  1824   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | INVITED |  1835K|    10M|       |  3038   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the ANTI JOIN method does not need to perform the sort and ends up being about half the cost of the MINUS version.